# Make sure to call the ageDifference function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop, object

I am trying to learn JavaScript and am stuck on a task (get the difference in age between alice and billy).  I wrote the following code but I am getting a error:

> Oops, try again. Make sure to call the ageDifference function.

```
// Our person constructor
function Person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

// We can make a function which takes persons as arguments
// This one computes the difference in ages between two people
var ageDifference = function(person1, person2) {
  return person1.age - person2.age;
}

var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);

// get the difference in age between alice and billy using our function
var diff = ageDifference("Alice", "Billy");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the names to the function, you need to pass the objects.

```
var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);

// get the difference in age between alice and billy using our function
var diff = ageDifference(alice,  billy);
```

Lets talk a little more about why your first approach was wrong.  We've all started programming somewhere and its understandable as to why you passed a string to the function, first of all lets take a look at the method signature.

```
function ageDifference( Person person1, Person person2 )
```

**NOTE**: *This is not JavaScript notation as you cannot explicitly declare parameter types as it is not a statically typed language, however we can assume that this function was created to accept `Person` objects.*

A `Person` at a high level may look like:

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

When you created `bob` and `alice` you `constructed` them, meaning you created a new instance in memory of the `Person` object.  You passed in a string for their name and an integer for their age. In memory we can now assume that the following variables exist within our current scope.

```
var alice[ name: "Alice", age: "25" ];
var bob  [ name: "Bob",   age: "30" ];
```

^ This illustrates that two objects exist with different values associated against their array keys.  This is probably the most important step to remember, you can now perform comparisons between the two objects by accessing these keys, for example:

```
bob.age - alice.age = 5
```

Would equate to

```
30 - 25 = 5
```

Knowing this we can now understand why your first approach to solving your problem was giving you errors.  By definition a string is an array of characters, and therefore you are not able to perform methods which don't exist on that type, such as `.age`.

I'd also note that right now you could get a negative difference if you pass billy in as the first person, in order to fix this you should find the minimum age and subtract it from the maximum.

```
function ageDifference(person1, person2)
{
      var max = Math.max(person1.age, person2.age);
      var min = Math.min(person1.age, person2.age);

      return max - min;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Worth explaining a bit more about variables vs. strings to help the questioner understand *why* `alice` works but `"Alice"` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing a string into `ageDifference()` you need to pass your `alice` and `billy` instances

```
// Our person constructor 
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

// We can make a function which takes persons as arguments
// This one computes the difference in ages between two people
var ageDifference = function(person1, person2) {
    return person1.age - person2.age;
}

var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);

// get the difference in age between alice and billy using our function
var diff = ageDifference(alice, billy);

console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your function like this to avoid a negative difference

```
function ageDifference(p1, p2)
{
   return p2.age < p1.age ? p1.age - p2.age : p2.age - p1.age;          
}
```

Create person objects:

```
var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);
```

And get the difference:

```
var diff = ageDifference(alice,  billy);
```